# What software(s) are suited to simulate a water wheel generating 3D graphics?

Tags: software

What software(s) would you recommend to simulate a water wheel that will generate 3D graphics?

Comment: There is a dedicated stack exchange site for [software recomendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This was asked before.

Comment: @AJN I'll try it but I expect that to be just as superficial as a google search; I was hoping from feedback from engineers. If no one knows, it's ok, I know it's a small community. I'm doing it on Ansys Discovery already - but perhaps someone who actually works with this could chime in.

Comment: Still sounds like a question asking for Houdini. Thing is 3D graphics sounds like something youd use for movies or animation. Perhaps you should quantify what you need the graphics for.

Comment: what's a neckbeard? ... I always learn something new every day

Comment: try Unreal engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the options, I was surprised to find that Ansys Fluent did not provide the most detailed 3D simulation, but FLOW 3D and SimScale (cloud). Ansys Fluent generates a realistic 2D simulation, but a comparatively poorer 3D one, among the examples I could find.

[image: SOLIDWORKS Flow Simulation]

SOLIDWORKS Flow Simulation

[image: Ansys Fluent]

Ansys Fluent

[image: FLOW 3D]

FLOW 3D

[image: SimScale]

SimScale